# Find all integers such that $\sqrt{(n-4)\sqrt{n-19}}$ is also an integer.

Tags: solution-verification

This is my solution not sure if it is correct though.

Solution:
For the expression to be an integer, $(n-4)\sqrt{n-19}$ should be a perfect square. For $(n-4)\sqrt{n-19}$ to be a perfect square, $(n-4)^2(n-19)$ should be a perfect square.

Now consider some perfect square $k^2$ where $k\in\Bbb{Z}$. If I multiply it by some integer $r$ the perfect square will no longer be a perfect square unless $r=1,r=0,k=0$.

We see that above, $(n-4)^2$ is a perfect square and $n-19$ is some integer. So for  $(n-4)^2(n-19)$ to be a perfect square, $(n-4)^2$ must be zero or $(n-19)$ must be zero or one.

As a result there are three possible $n$'s such that the expression is an integer,
$n=4,n=19,n=20$.

Edit: This solution is wrong!

Comment: You can verify easily that $n=19$ is not a valid solution.

Comment: Note that n - 4√(n-19) ≠ (n-4)√(n-19)

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion I made

Comment: I will edit it.

Comment: The product of two perfect squares is also a perfect square , so your statement above in the third paragraph is wrong, $r$ can be any perfect square.

Comment: The answer may be correct but the solution is definitely wrong. For example the phrase starting with "If I multiply it by some integer r the perfect square will no longer be a perfect square unless..." is wrong.

Comment: Right... I will have to think about that.

Comment: Do you consider $n=4$ to be a solution?  It does need to go through the complex numbers to calculate the subterm $\sqrt{n-19}$ but the eventual value of the entire expression is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with $$n=s^2+19$$ and substitute that in and just follow the algebra you get 20 and 244.
$$\sqrt{(n-4)\sqrt{n-19}}=\sqrt{(s^2+15)s}=q$$
Then$$(s^2+15)s=q^2$$
$$s^3+15 s=q^2$$
Then this means that $$s|q$$ so $$q=s t$$
Then you get $$s^2+15=s t^2$$ by which you infer that $$s|15$$
You then try all the factors of 15 and get 20 or 244.

Comment: How about four? It is a solution right?

Comment: I think $st^2$ should be $s^2t^2$. So $s^2|15$.

Comment: No, the $s$ gets cancelled both the sides

Comment: So the solutions are $n=19,n=20,n=244$?

Comment: Yeah, 19 works.